# Django, I am getting "ERROR: Module: models could not be imported" while manage.py check or sync.db

Tags: python, django, eclipse

After I add my application to INSTALLED_APPS section I can't make 
`python manage.py check` - it returns an error. 
Would you, please, help me to find out what I am doing wrong?

1) [console window with an error @line55 of models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anxOq.png)

text of the console:

> (py350-dja185-venv)MacBook-Pro:recipe_1_1 mac1$ python manage.py check
>   shell Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 10,
>   in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 351, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 325, in execute
>       django.setup()   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/**init**.py",
>   line 18, in setup
>       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py",
>   line 108, in populate
>       app_config.import_models(all_models)   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py",
>   line 198, in import_models
>       self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/**init**.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 986, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 969, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 673, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 662, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 222, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/Users/mac1/Documents/workspace/recipe_1_1/meals/models.py", line 55,
>   in 
>       class Ingredients(models.Model):   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 308, in **new**
>       new_class._prepare()   File "/Users/mac1/Envs/py350-dja185-venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
>   line 361, in _prepare
>       cls.**doc** = "%s(%s)" % (cls.**name**, ", ".join(f.name for f in opts.fields)) TypeError: sequence item 7: expected str instance, int
>   found

2) piece of code @models.py Why does it give me an error at line 55?

```
36-39 MEASUREMENT_CHOICES = (('шт', 'штук'), ...,)

41 class Recipe(models.Model):
42     recipe_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
43     meal_id = models.ForeignKey('Meal')
44     ingredient_id = models.ForeignKey('Ingredients', related_name = '+')
45     ingr_quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
46     ingr_measurement = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices = MEASUREMENT_CHOICES)
47     tail = models.CharField(max_length = 35) 

49 SEASON_CHOICES = ((u'01', u'январь'), (u'02', u'февраль'), (u'03', u'март'),
                  (u'04', u'апрель'), (u'05', u'май'), (u'06', u'июнь'),
                  (u'07', u'июль'), (u'08', u'август'), (u'09', u'сентябрь'),
                  (u'10', u'октябрь'), (u'11', u'ноябрь'), (u'12', u'декабрь'),  
                  )

55 class Ingredients(models.Model):
56    ingr_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
57    ingr_category = models.ForeignKey('IngrCategory') 
58    calories_raw = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
59    calories_boiled = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
60    calories_fried = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
61    ingr_unit = models.CharField(10)
62    price_in_season = models.DecimalField(7,2)
63    price_in_no_season = models.DecimalField(7,2)
64    price_current = models.DecimalField(7,2)
65    season = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = SEASON_CHOICES)
```

Somehow, it goes through the class Recipe, and through the previous class also, and gives me an error at the `class Ingredients(models.Model)` line. Why?

3) eclipse window - same project, different error types:

> Finding files... done.
>   Importing test modules ... done.
>   Traceback (most recent call last): <...>
>   File "/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.python.pydev_4.3.0.201508182223/pysrc/pydev_runfiles.py", line 813, in run_tests
>       raise AssertionError("Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.")
>   AssertionError: Unable to run suite with DjangoTestSuiteRunner because it couldn't be imported.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It it full `Ingredients` class code shown here?

Comment: Next time please paste console context as text in the question not a picture pasted somewhere in the void.

Comment: Which is the value of `MEASUREMENT_CHOICES`?

Comment: Michal F, no, the Ingredients class is not full shown here.

trinchet, MEASUREMENT_CHOICES is written in Russian, type is string, maximum 5 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in absence of "max_digits = " and "decimal_places = "

```
62    price_in_season = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 7, decimal_places = 2)
```

This field is a number 7 of the sequence in Ingredients class.